# Can I use admob in my android app if my google developer console and my admob account are registered with different countries?

Tags: android, google-play, admob, adsense, country

I recently moved to another country and want to put an ad in my app published in my old google developer account that says that my location is still the same. Does my admob and google accounts will be banned if I create an admob account with my current location and then put an ad in a app published in my old google developer account? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can i have done so much time. 
this what tells you that this add is yours
`<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>`